# Paypal API: get all recurring payments

Tags: paypal

Since that Paypal APIs does not offer any exposed method to retrive all the recurrent payment, which means active/deactivated/suspended payments, is there any chance to get there?

Comment: I wrote this question 'cause not a single Google's result gives a proper answer, even a link to the official guide which is not sufficient.

Comment: This is not a python related question. I have tagged it with PayPal.

Comment: @PaulWasilewski thanks: I wasn't able to do that in principle 'cause I've not enough reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a deep research, after asking additional details to the development Paypal's team there's not a single exposed methods from their APIs which allows to obtain a complete list of subscription ***so far***.

The only one way available to obtain lists of subscriptions, independently from theirselves statuses, it's to web-scrape (eg. with Selenium) the web pages.